# How to get value from dynamic create input in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have created a custom form and added some jquery for dynamic inputs, but I can't get values from these generated inputs (**Elements, Link, Image**). Here are my form and code.

[image] 
**Template**
This is my template for this form

```
<form id="workForm" class="workAdd">
<label>Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
<label>Live Link</label>
<input type="text" name="llink" id="llink" class="form-control">
<label>Elements Used In This Project</label>
<div class="row" id="eleContainer">
    <div class="eleRow">
        <div class="col s6 m6 l6">
            <label>Element</label>
            <input type="text" name="elements[]" id="elementsid[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col s6 m6 l6">
            <label>Link</label>
            <input type="text" name="elinks[]" id="elinksid[]" class="form-control" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--row-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s6 m12 center">
        <a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light" id="addElements"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="imgContainer">
    <div class="imgRow">
        <label>Image</label>
        <input type="text" name="image[]" id="imageid[]" class="form-control" >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s6 m12 center">
        <a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light" id="addImages"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<label>Detail</label>
<textarea id="detail" class="materialize-textarea" name="detail" data-length="120"></textarea>

<button type="submit" id="work-submit" thisId="" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

**Meteor**
And this is my submit event I have created for this form.

```
Template.addworkTemp.events({
"submit .workAdd": function(event) {

    var title = event.target.title.value;
    var llink = event.target.llink.value;
    var elements = event.target.elements.value;
    var elinks = event.target.elinks.value;
    var images = event.target.images.value;
    var detail = event.target.detail.value;
    return false;
```

Comment: You will have better success if you don't use square brackets in the input names and id's

Comment: @mikkel I know it gives me an error with brackets but  I have also tried without bracket but nothing, not anything. please give me some idea what should I do. I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good [tutorial on meteor forms](http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/forms/) that might be useful to you. This tutorial is based on blaze which is what you're using.

Firstly you can attach your handler to the `form` instead of to the `workform` class.

```
Template.addWorkTemp.events({
  'submit form'(event) {
  ...
  }
});
```

Then you should prevent the default form action:

```
Template.addWorkTemp.events({
  'submit form'(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
  }
});
```

The `event` object has a `target` property which has properties for every field based on the *name* attached to them in the html.

```
Template.addWorkTemp.events({
  'submit form'(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.llink.value);
    ...
  }
});
```

I have no idea why you're appending `[]` to the field names. I'm not sure those are valid in that context.

There's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27201971/2805154) that shows how to access the form elements via the `template` object which is an optional second parameter to your event handler. That might also help you.

When I'm debugging things like this I normally set a breakpoint (using the browser's development tools) at the first line of the event handler then inspect the event to make sure I understand what's inside.